# Rendering a blazor ComponentBase to string

Tags: c#, razor-pages, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to write code for sending emails rendered from razor components. I have a working version of this in standard MVC, using `IRazorViewEngine` and `ITempDataProvider`, but they require me to have an `IView`. I am wondering if this can be achieved using the new `ComponentBase` objects. I know the `IHtmlHelper.RenderComponentAsync<MyComponent>()` will render to string but I don't know how to instantiate `HtmlHelper` properly outside of a razor view, so there may be something more appropriate to use. If i have the `ComponentBase` object, how could I go about rendering it to a string?

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late reply but I had the same question, and figured out ...

If you can modify the source of the component you can add a method like this:

```cs
public partial class Component1
{
    public void AddToTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        this.BuildRenderTree(builder);
    }
}
```

You need access to the source of the component since `ComponentBase.BuildRenderTree` is protected.

Then elsewhere you can do:

```cs
Component1 component = new Component1();
RenderTreeBuilder renderTreeBuilder = new RenderTreeBuilder();
component.AddToTree(renderTreeBuilder);
var frames = renderTreeBuilder.GetFrames();
string renderedString = frames.Array[0].TextContent;
```

Not sure exactly how the frames work, and why the array returns so many frames, and why most of them are full of null values, with just the first one actually meaningful .. but it seems to work so I'm ignoring all of that ‍♂️

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure what triggered that comment from the bot but I thought this was a good answer. Still have yet to try it out though.